# Creating a new navigation stack with a flip transition instead of pushing another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitabbarcontroller

I had this code to make a flip transition between UITabControllers:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"OtherSb" bundle:nil];
PrimaryTabBarController *tabBarController = [sb  instantiateInitialViewController];

[UIView transitionWithView:[APP_DELEGATE window]
                  duration:0.8
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    [[APP_DELEGATE window] setRootViewController:tabBarController];
                    [[APP_DELEGATE window] makeKeyAndVisible];
                }
                completion:nil];
```

However, strangely, during the flip transition, the tab bar briefly flashes from the bottom to the top of the screen.  I was able to make that stop by doing the following:

```
PrimaryTabBarController *tabBarController = [sb  instantiateInitialViewController];

tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:tabBarController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem with this however is that I'm pushing another view controller onto the stack which can easily run through the memory.  How can I create a new navigation stack without having the tab bar mess up the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rootViewController` is not very animatable property as you can imagine. `makeKeyAndVisible` is not animatable either and you should probably do that before you run any animations.

This API itself is very old (iOS 4.0) and I personally consider it more of a legacy of UIKit and I haven't seen it being used since iOS 6 when flipping views was still a thing.

Custom transitions introduced in iOS 7 is a very comfortable way of doing any kind of crazy animations however as you noticed, it creates a modal hierarchy that you don't always need.

All of these API were designed to work with *sibling* views within container. This is something mentioned in documentation and its samples. And it seems like that UIWindow is not suitable as global animation container.

Sample code from documentation:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
           duration:0.2
           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
           animations:^{ [fromView removeFromSuperview]; [containerView addSubview:toView]; }
           completion:NULL];
```

I suggest that you follow the same logic as custom transitions and first setup dummy root controller that will serve you as a container for animation.

Then you add your views or entire view controllers inside of it and run animation between sibling views using

```
+ transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`
```

*or*

```
- transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

*or*

```
+ transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:
```

In addition to that, there is a useful flag `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews` that will automatically hide the flipped view to avoid it to flicker or re-appear after animation.

When animation is over, you can swap the entire root controller in one call, that should be unnoticed to user.

This API has some quirks too, for example if by any chance you use it when the app is not on screen or you run it on a window that is not currently visible, then it will simply swallow the call. I used to have a check like

```
if(fromViewController.view.window) { 
    /* run animations */ 
} else { 
    /* swap controllers without animations */ 
}
```

I made a sample project to demonstrate how to use temporary container view for transition

https://github.com/pronebird/FlipRootController

Sample category on UIWindow:

```
@implementation UIWindow (Transitions)

- (void)transitionToRootController:(UIViewController *)newRootController animationOptions:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options {
    // get references to controllers
    UIViewController *fromVC = self.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *toVC = newRootController;

    // setup transition view
    UIView *transitionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];

    // add subviews into transition view
    [transitionView addSubview:toVC.view];
    [transitionView addSubview:fromVC.view];

    // add transition view into window
    [self addSubview:transitionView];

    // flush any outstanding animations
    // UIButton may cancel transition if this method is called from touchUpInside, etc..
    [CATransaction flush];

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromVC.view
                        toView:toVC.view
                      duration:0.5
                       options:options
                    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        // set new root controller after animation
                        self.rootViewController = toVC;

                        // move VC's view out of transition view
                        [self addSubview:toVC.view];

                        // remove transition view
                        [transitionView removeFromSuperview];
                    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will do this.  The one problem I'm having is that I can't call the flip method on the container view from the views inside of it.  Each side of the application has a complicated view hierarchy.  Should I keep passing a reference to the containerView whenever I go to a new view controller? This seems pretty cumbersome. Should I make a singleton?

Comment: @JohnFarkerson it depends how you organize your app. You can make a global animation manager that would wrap views into container view during animation and then swap root controller and delete container after animations complete.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! You can't imagine how helpful this was to me.  I now have it working!